# Installing joomla on Microsoft IIS

Tags: iis, content-management-system, joomla

i tried to install joomla using the microsoft web platform installer. I was able to install joomla, php and mysql successfully.

However when i browse the website from the IIS, it says page cannot be found..

What am i missing..please let me know

Its been more than 2 days i am trying this...

Answer (score 1):

Try to install it using this tool [Microsoft Web Platform Installer 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx), it will help you setup everything. Because may be there is something you missed such as setup the iis to handle php files.

Comment: Yes.. i installed with the microsoft web platform...but i couldnt browse the index.php page...

Comment: hmmm, are you sure index.php is in its right place? try to browse any other page, for example try to go to the admin.